# Ember unit test rendering handlebars returns null or undefined

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js

I am trying to write unit tests for rendering a handlebar component. When the test gets ran the object is empty and no HTML is generated. I have followed this same layout using other components and they render properly. I am confused why the returned object is null/undefined

here is my ember test code:

```
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';

moduleForComponent('csv-upload', 'Integration | Component | csv upload', {
     integration: true
});

test('it renders', function(assert) {
assert.expect(2);


this.render(hbs`{{csv-upload}}`);

assert.equal(this.$().text().trim(), '');

// Template block usage:
this.render(hbs`
  {{#csv-upload}}
   template block text
  {{/csv-upload}}
`);

assert.equal(this.$().text().trim(), '');
});
```

the output from the test is:

```
ok 32 PhantomJS 2.1 - JSHint - integration/pods/components/csv-upload/component-test.js: should pass jshint
not ok 33 PhantomJS 2.1 - Integration | Component | device actions: it renders
---
    actual: >
        null
```

another thing from output:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.get('selected').isAny')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your component expects some properties to be set (`selected`) in our case. Since that is undefined, the component won't render properly, which in turn makes the test fail. Try to pass in the `selected` property to your component, and see if that helps.

**Note:** This is the original comment converted into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from [Jesper Haug Karsrud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104465/jesper-haug-karsrud)  is the correct answer! Thank you!

To correct the problem the properties must be set for the component before rendering. The changes to correct the problem:

```
this.set('myProperty', 'fakedata');
this.render(hbs`{{csv-upload data=myProperty}}`);
assert.equal(this.$().html(), '<input id="ember580" type="file" class="ember-view ember-text-field">');
```

Comment: One thing to keep in mind, `this.$()` is the test container and not the rendered component